# ¿Cómo puedo pasar un ConnectionString a un CrystalReport?

Tags: c#

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
ReportDocument rpt = new ReportDocument();
rpt.Load(ruta);

rpt.SetParameterValue("@ActionRequestID", accion);
rpt.SetParameterValue("@LanguageID", len);
rpt.DataSourceConnections[0].SetConnection("servidor","database","user","password");
```

Ahora necesito hacer la conexión con un `CrystalReport` utilizando un `ConnectionString` desde el **web.config**, solo que el método `DataSourceConnections` recibe 4 parámetros para la conexión.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Listo colegas logre resolver el problema, aquí la solución por si a alguien mas tiene la misma duda:

```
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder conb = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder();

        conb.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectioStringName"].ConnectionString;

        string server = conb.DataSource;
        string db = conb.InitialCatalog;
        string user = conb.UserID;
        string pwd = conb.Password;

        rpt.DataSourceConnections[0].SetConnection(server,db,user,pwd);
```

Comment: Gracias por la retroalimentación, Marca tu respuesta con la palomita por favor.